# What is the best way to prepare data for pagination with custom range

Tags: javascript, angular, api, observable

I'm building simple Angular app to display data from [Star Wars API](https://swapi.co/api/planets/). I want to create pagination with custom range (5,10 or 20 elements per page). API returns only 10 elements in single request, so how to prepare data to display if user could change range from default 10 to 20 records per page? Should I iterate over API and store all possible data before I even display the view? What is the Angular way in that case?

Comment: you can use paginators with a table to achieve that in Angular. You can checkout paginators of Primeng, ngZorro, Angular material

Comment: Thx @SebaCherian it's great solution for the view :) But what about the data? API returns only 10 records per request?

Comment: For your custom range 5,10 data will be available from the API, but for range 20, you have to request two times the api. So you can use mergeMap or forkJoin or promise.resolveAll then only display the data.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar but if need to add 25 elements instead of 20 then I should make 3 requests? I got it. I'm using Observable to get data but I don't how to use mergeMap in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the case only if the api consumed is delivering 10 records in a single request. Otherwise you can just pass number of records and offset to the api to get the desired result.

Use `change` event handler on `select` tag as

```
<select (change)="fetchRecords()" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" name="gender">
      <option *ngFor="let option of selectOptions" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </option>
</select>
```

Use `forkjoin` from `rxjs` to get results of 2 api calls for records 1-20.

```
public selectOptions = [
    "5",
    "10",
    "20"
  ];    

fetchRecords() {
      console.log(this.selectedOption);
      if(this.selectedOption == "5") {
        this.http.get(requestUrl1).subscribe(data=> {
          // fetch 1-10 records, but put 1-5 in the array to show
        });
      }
      if(this.selectedOption == "10") {
        this.http.get(requestUrl1).subscribe(data=> {
          // fetch 1-10 records, put all 10 records in array to show
        });
      }
      if(this.selectedOption == "20") {
      let response1 = this.http.get(requestUrl1); // 1-10 offset
      let response2 = this.http.get(requestUrl2); // 11-20 offset
      forkJoin([response1, response2, response3]).subscribe(responseList => {
                this.responseData1 = responseList[0];
                this.responseData2 = responseList[1];
                // concate all the 20 records and put in the array to show
            });
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Angular**

You can use paginators with a table/ table with paginator to achieve that in Angular. You can checkout paginators/data tables of Primeng, ngZorro and Angular material which provides a variety of features inbuilt.

Checkout various paginators that can be used with table- [PrimeNg](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/paginator), [ngZorro](https://ng.ant.design/components/pagination/en), [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview)

Checkout various data tables with pagination - [PrimeNg](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/lazy), [ngZorro](https://ng.ant.design/components/table/en#components-table-demo-row-selection-and-operation), [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#pagination)

**API**

If api returns 10 records per request, initially when the table with paginator is loaded you can request records from 0 to 10, i.e. for page 1 in paginator. Then when you click on page 2, you can request next 10 records, i.e. 11 to 20 and so on.

> When you call api from client you should add details like the **number
>   of records to fetch** and the **offset from which you want to fetch**
>   the data and fetch the data based on those values. For example in C#,
>   there's an option called skip() and take() where you can provide those
>   two values

Comment: I understood, but what to do if the user will change the pagination range to 20 or to 5 from default 10 records? I don't know how to build such flexible service.

Comment: In Angular, there are functions which gets triggered when you change range, i.e. to 5,10 or 20 or when you click on a page number. So you can know what is the limit that is set in the function and call the api accordingly. Did you get what I meant?

Comment: What functions? My main problem is that the swAPI is paginated to 10 elements per request. So if I set pagination to (5,10 and 25) and when I change range to 25 elements per page I should make 3 requests?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190764/discussion-between-seba-cherian-and-enk1).